# Hibernate query on many to many relationship with extra column

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate and I am trying to figure out how to query a many to many relationship mapped as an entity due to the need of an extra column.

In particular, following the example I found at codejava.net (http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example) I mapped the relation like this:

Student.java

```
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    // Constructor, getters, setters, hashcode, equals
 }
```

Course.java

```
@Entity
@Table( 
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
                            columnNames {"name","year"})
)
public class Course implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String year;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course")
    private Set<Student_Course> students = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    // Constructor, getters, setters, hashcode, equals
}
```

Student_Course.java

```
@Entity
public class Student_Course implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private long id; 

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_email")
    private Student student;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    private Course course;

    @Column(nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "int default 0")
    private int score;

    // Constructor, getters, setters, hashcode, equals
}
```

Now what I want to achieve is to find out, with an hql query, the names and surnames of students enrolled in a given course (I know the name and the year of the course).
I know this is probably easy, but I can't produce a working query in HQL.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this query can do what you want:

```
SELECT sc.student.name, sc.student.surname
FROM Course c JOIN c.students sc 
WHERE c.name = :name AND c.year = :year
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.

Comment: This approach works and I like it because it doesn't require a subquery and it is very concise. So I am accepting this answer even if the answer proposed by @omkar sirra is working too. Unfortunately I have not enough reputation to upvote your answer omkar, but thank you anyway.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me @Andrea marcolin. I personally dont like Joins as I feel It increase the time complexity. I removed the subquery and optimized the query now

Comment: @omkarsirra it will work without On clause because Hibernate can handle this automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your response @ Leonardo Luiz

Answer (score 0):

```
Select name, surname from Student where email in 
(Select student.email from Student_Course 
where Student_course.course.name=:courseName and Student_course.course.year= :year)
```

and then set both courseName and year

Update

```
Select student.name,student.surname from Student_Course 
where Student_course.course.name=:courseName and Student_course.course.year= :year
```

Comment: Probably a cleaner approach, even if, again, I prefer @Leonardo Luiz answer because he doesn't query directly the joining table, but he starts from the Course table and then do a join. Anyway, thank again for your patience and time.

Comment: I am not competing with others answers :D.Thanks!